# What is the length of side BC in the triangle?

Tags: geometry

If in a triangle ABC,BE and CF are the two medians perpendicular to each other and, if AB = 19 cm and AC = 22 cm then the length of

Answer (score 1):

[image]

#### Hint:

$$\begin{cases}
x^2+(2y)^2=11^2
\\
(2x)^2+y^2=(9,5)^2
\end{cases}$$
$$(1)+(2) \Rightarrow 5x^2+5y^2=121+81,25 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=\frac{121+81,25}{5}$$
Then $AB^2=(2x)^2+(2y)^2=4(x^2+y^2)$